# Android 3 Activitys - how to hande passing data?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So I just want to clarify the life cycles a little. I have three activitys A(main), B and C. B is startet from A with some extra infromation, that it needs to show the correct content. Now B starts the Activity C (no extra content needed). 
Can now (Activity C is in foreground) activity B be killed? If so, when pressing the back button, do I need to transfer that same infromation from C -> B, that was transfered at the first creation of B? Basically, what I wnat to know is, if extra content is used to start activity from parent activity, should this same extra content be used to start the activity from its child?

Thank you
Jaka

Comment: Why don't you use `Preference`? or for small data use `Application` Class to get/set data.

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass back data from C -> B when you press back button.
On B's onCreate, store the additional data into private class variables and you can use it when the activity is restored.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was just reading through this article (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html), and as I understand it, it seems like  onSaveInstanceState already does all the work. Or am I misunderstanding this.